# how to get first news of any category in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

i created 2 table News and Category at models.py file in my Django project. I use
first_news  = News.objects.first() to have the first news in database. How can i do if i want to get first news of any category?

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying get first news of any category use

```
News.objects.all().order_by("id")
```

if you want first news of a given category use

```
News.objects.filter(category=your_category).order_by("id")
```

Comment: News.objects.filter(category=sports).order_by("id") is not working for me. I have this problem (Field 'id' expected a number but got 'sports'.)

Comment: Show us your models.py , or at least the structure of News and Categories Class